# how to bundle google API calls for Place Search Requests?

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am using the "Place Search Requests" from google:

A Place Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters

But the problem is I have to make hundreds of queries to google and this makes the APP very very slow.

Could I somehow bundle the requests at once? For example, I can send all the names of the places to google and get the result back in a row?

Regards, Yashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can only do what the documentation says will work.**

*Side note:* Bulk downloads of data are forbidden by the Terms. It's open to question why you need to make hundreds of queries, and indeed whether your use case is allowed.

Comment: I am trying to show annotations to a map for a list of companies, for this reason, I need to get the coordinates of each company. Maybe I should get the coordinates in another program and save them somewhere and use the data in my App?